# Url Detection using Jscript

Tags: javascript, css

This is the javascrip that i have implemented for url detection in a plain text 
but when i am clicking on the link i am not able to open the link in new tab it is opening the localhost address before the website.

Example : i have detected www.google.com

when i am clicking on it i am getting this

```
(localhost:3415/Home/www.google.com)
```

i want only www.google.com to be open in new tab

<-- Code -->

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function test() {
   dt(document.getElementById('d').value);
  }
  function dt(t) {
   // find links wo www and http. bla.bla.TLD(ANY query)

    var srg = new RegExp(/(^|\b)([\w.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(?:\:[0-9]{1,5})?(?:\/.*)?)([,\s]|$)/ig);

    var r = t.replace(srg, '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

    document.getElementById('c').innerHTML = r;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: You need to add `http://` at the start.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum where ?? i have to add? i want default for all the text when i enter it ?

Comment: and also having problem with url such as www.hacking-ethical.com?can you help me
?

Comment: Create a fiddle on jsfiddle.net illustrating your issue. Generally, you can avoid regex altogether here in favor of much simpler code.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It works by changing the regex :)